# how to access ed:arc from code behind in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this ed:arc defined in my wpf project:

```
<ed:Arc x:Name="TimerArc" ArcThickness="5" EndAngle="360" ArcThicknessUnit="Pixel" Fill="#FC17A086" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=UserControl}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=UserControl}" Stretch="None" />
```

i wondered how can i access this arc and change its values from the .cs file of the window?

Comment: May be you can access it by `Name` property like `TimerArc`.

Comment: you are right! interesting why x:name doesn't work but the name property works..